# My print statement keeps on printing even though the condition is false

Tags: python, if-statement

I am making a rock paper scissors game, and I made an if statement for an invalid input. But, whenever I put in a right input, it still prints invalid input.

Code:

```
import random

round_count = int(input("How many rounds would you like to play? "))
score = 0

for i in range(int(round_count)):

 computer_choice = random.choice(["rock", "paper", "scissors"])

 player_choice = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors? ").lower()

 if computer_choice == player_choice:
    print("Tie")
    # add_round_for_tie = input("Would you like to add a round because of the tie?")
    # if add_round_for_tie.lower() == "yes":
    # round_count += 1

 else:
    if computer_choice == "paper" and player_choice == "scissors":
        print("Scissors beats paper. You win!")
        score += 1
    if computer_choice == "scissors" and player_choice == "paper":
        print("Scissors beats paper. You lost.")
    if computer_choice == "rock" and player_choice == "scissors":
        print("Rock beats scissors. You lost.")
    if computer_choice == "scissors" and player_choice == "rock":
        print("Rock beats scissors. You win!")
        score += 1
    if computer_choice == "paper" and player_choice == "rock":
        print("Paper beats rock. You lost.")
    if computer_choice == "rock" and player_choice == "paper":
        print("Paper beats rock. You win!")
        score += 1

 if player_choice != "rock" or player_choice != "paper" or player_choice != "scissors":
    print("Invalid input")

print(f"Your score is {score}/{round_count}")
```

In the console, this is what happens:

```
How many rounds would you like to play? 2
Rock, Paper, Scissors? rock
Paper beats rock. You lost.
Invalid input
Rock, Paper, Scissors? paper
Paper beats rock. You win!
Invalid input
Your score is 1/2
```

Comment: Sidenote: you already have `round_count` as an int. `for i in range(round_count):`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple logic error.  Consider the expression used in the if statement:

```
if player_choice != "rock" or player_choice != "paper" or player_choice != "scissors":
    print("Invalid input")
```

This will always be true.  If `player_choice` is not `"rock"`, then is will be true.  But if it is `"rock"`, then it will not be `"paper"`, so it will again be true.

Change the `or` operators to `and`:

```
if player_choice != "rock" and player_choice != "paper" and player_choice != "scissors":
    print("Invalid input")
```

You could achieve this more concisely as:

```
if player_choice not in ("rock", "paper", "scissors"):
    print("Invalid input")
```

Note that you could simplify this code considerably by making the valid input check up front, before checking who won (that's is how it would normally be done), and also using `if`-`elif` chains to reduce the number of redundant comparisons.

Comment: Alternatively `not(player_choice == "rock" or player_choice == "paper" or player_choice == "scissors)` will also work. Depending on how you think about the logic here, Tom's suggestion might feel more natural or this alternative might feel more natural. But they are both logically equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by the wrong use of operators. There is already an answer pointing out the error and gives the right solution. But I want to add why it doesn't work, which isn't explained.

Suppose you have a variable `n = 1`, and you want to check if it is equal to 1 or 2 or 3, you use the following expression:

```
n != 1 or n != 2 or n != 3
```

What happens? The expression is always `True` for any input.

Why?

The output of `OR` is `True` if one of the inputs is `True`, its truth table is:

```
False OR False -> False
False OR True -> True
True OR False -> True
True OR True -> True
```

In your expression, the conditions are checked from left to right until a `True` is found, the expression is `True` if any of the conditions is `True`.

If `n == 1`, the first expression is `False`, so Python continues to evaluate the second expression, `1 != 2` is `True`, Python found a `True` so the whole expression is `True`, and stops evaluation.

If `n == 2`, the first expression is `True`, so the whole expression is `True`.

If `n == 3`, the first expression is `True`.

For any other input, the first expression is always `True`.

For input 1, the truth values are: `False, True`. For any other input the first expression is always `True`. Thus your expression is always `True`.

And the other expression using logic `and`, the output of `AND` is `True` if and only if both its operands are `True`.

Truth table of `AND`:

```
False AND False -> False
False AND True -> False
True AND False -> False
True AND True -> True
```

Using this expression `n != 1 and n != 2 and n != 3`, Python evaluates the conditions from left to right and for it to be `True` then all of its components must be `True`. Conversely, if any of the expressions is `False`, the whole expression is `False` and Python stops evaluation.

For `n == 1`, the first expression is `False`, so the whole expression is `False`,

For `n == 2`, the first is `True`, but the second is `False`. So the expression is `False`.

For `n == 3`, you have two `True`, but the last is `False`, so the expression is `False`.

For any other input, the expression is `True` as it should.